# WebRTC fallback

Tags: html, flash, video-streaming, webrtc

I am trying to choose the right way to organize conference video chat from browser. It should work both on iPad/iPhone/Chrome/etc(with WebRTC and without Flash sometimes) and on IE/Firefox/etc(with Flash and without WebRTC sometimes).

Is it known working solution for working with WebRTC from flash or I need to organize such fallback on server-side?

Comment: Any update about this?

Comment: @FrEaKmAn I didn't find any solution for flash drop-in replacement of native WebRTC. As web calls aren't our service's primary functionality we disable it in IE / Safari and other creepy browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Flash do not support WebRTC, and there are no third party libs which can make it to do this. You can try to find WebRTC <-> RTMP gateway to connect your apps. If there is no such gateway than you still can use 2 gateways: WebRTC <-> SIP <-> RTMP.